# How do I use strtok with every single nonalpha character as a delimeter? (C)

Tags: c, file

So I have a string:

```
**BOB**123(*&**blah**02938*(*&91820**FOO**
```

I want to be able to use `strtok` to deliminate each word. The delimiter is every single character that is not a letter.

I was suggested to us `isalpha`, but not sure how I would go about this. Is there a way to do this without naming every single non-alpha character?

Unfortunately NOT allowed to use regex libraries.

Comment: Please post you current attempt, i.e. what have you tried? Also googling "strtok examples" gives a lot of, well, examples...

Comment: I suggest you look into using a regular expression library... your requirements are stretching the limits of the standard library... here is an example: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: Should a solution assume `char` is 8 bits or the more general `CHAR_MIN...CHAR_MAX`?

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *strtok_t(char *str, int (*test)(int ch)){
    static char *store = NULL;
    char *token;
    if(str != NULL){
        store = str;
    }
    if(store == NULL) return NULL;
    while(*store && !test(*store)){//skip delimiter
        ++store;
    }
    if(*store == '\0') return NULL;
    token=store;
    while(*store && test(*store)){
        ++store;
    }

    if(*store == '\0'){
        store = NULL;
    } else {
        *store++ = '\0';
    }
    return token;
}

int main(void){
    char str[128] = "BOB123(&blah02938(*&91820FOO";
    char *token;
    for(token = strtok_t(str, isalpha); token ; token = strtok_t(NULL, isalpha)){
        printf("%s\n", token);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If one wishes to keep numbers too, (s)he can use `isalnum()`, instead of `isalpha()`. Don't forget to change both calls to `strtok_t()` though! Nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

One approach that can make this easier is to first overwrite all non-alpha characters with spaces:

```
for (char *p = str; *p; p++)
    if (!isalpha(*p)) *p = ' ';
```

Now you can use `strtok(str, " ")`

Comment: Very very nice.  Nicely portable too (except should be  `if (!isalpha((unsigned char) (*p)))` as `isalpha()` is only defined for `unsigned char` and `EOF`).  I was wondering how a solution could be had if `char` was 16 (or 32) bits.  This approach made it all easy.  Slick.

Answer (score 1):

at first, you will have to create a list of non-alpha chars :

```
char *myString = "fhewuidnjkl123782107381290z890zh";
char nonAlphachars[0xFF];
memset(nonAlphachars, 0, 0xFF);
int i = 0;    
int c = 1;
for(; c <= 0xFF; c++)
{
   if(!isalpha(c))
   {
      nonAlphachars[i++] = c;
   }
}
```

this will enable you to use `strtok` with `myString` :

```
char *tok = strtok(myString, nonAlphachars);
```

Now you will only need to iterate over your tokens aaand you're done. Mind you : thats only a untested (!) draft but i guess you'll get the idea.
If you want your program to be efficient : hardcode all of the nonalpha-chars in a seperate string, discard the loop altogether and use it ... ugly but VERY fast (unlike all of the other answers)

by the way : these are all of the nonalpha chars in their numeric representation, just spot the gap and ... i'll leave that one to you ;-) :

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 91 92 93 94 95 96 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255
```

Comment: it is nullterminated. Verily. In fact, the whole string is full of 0, initially. What does "UB" mean?

Comment: As an author of "one of the other answers" I'd like more than your word that your version with hard-coded delimiter string is faster than all the othzer solutions. There are no requirements on the delimiter string, so `strtok` can only start looking from the beginning for each character. The `isalpha` function is only a single look-up in an array. I bet it's rather slow. (It's okay for a single, short line, though.)

Comment: 1) What does "UB" mean?  Undefined behavior.  2) I now see the `memset(nonAlphachars, 0, 0xFF);` effectively null terminating as long as at least 1 non-alpha was found - which is expected.

Comment: exacty opposite of undefined : http://codepad.org/6em3ou7x
Keep learning, you're getting there. And : no, memset doesnt care about isAlpha. In fact, memset doesnt care about anything - memset only knows execution.

Comment: Yes, `memset()` does not care about `isalpha()`. But the algorithm does care. Should `isalpha()` never become true - which is certainly not expected, `nonAlphachars` would end up with-out a `'\0'` termination.  The nifty trick to pre-initialized   `nonAlphachars` to `0` creates the candidate `'\0'`.  But a simple `nonAlphachars[i] = '\0';` after the loop would be faster than `memset()` and explicit.  Could have made the array (2*26-1) smaller as certainly at least  "A-Z" and "a-z" will be `isalpha()`.  Alternatively, could have made the array 256 or `CHAR_MAX-CHAR_MIN+1` to insure portability.

Comment: OR one could simply use a hardcoded string and forget about efficiency altogether.

Comment: Regarding your bold statement "ugly but VERY fast": Performance of `strtok` degrades with long delimiter strings, so that claim certainly doesn't hold. (Whether the non-alpha string is computed once or hard-coded doesn't matter. Your solution is fast enough for everyday parsing, but not VERY fast in all caps.)

Comment: so what you're saying is that strtok isnt efficient enough? In that case you should write your own strtok (re-inventing the wheel is always error-prone) or simply use ASM. Efficiency isnt actually a topic anymore, with DDR4, pthreads and octa-core CPUs one can easily parse gigabytes of text (in RAM) without having massive execution-times - which is much more than anyone could want; even if you use strtok.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* probably use `strtok` for this, but it's probably easier to roll your own. Below is an example that uses a custom struct to hold the state and the results of the tokeniser. The state is just a pointer into the string, which must be initialised with the string to tokenise.

The result represents a substring of that string as combination of starting pointer and length. That result is not zero-terminated, so you have to take care. This approach has the benefit that the solution doesn't allocate extra memory and doesn't overwrite the original string, so unlike `strtok` it works on read-only strings.

The tokeniser itself is invoked with a function that returns 1 or 0, depending on whether a new token has been found, which makes for easy loop syntax.

Here goes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>      /* for isalpha(c) */

struct alpha_t {
    const char *p;      /* Pointer int string; must be initialised */
    const char *str;    /* start of current token */
    int len;            /* length of token */
};

/*
 *      Get next alpha token from string; alpha->p must be initialised
 *      to the (possible read-only) string to work on.
 */
int next_alpha(struct alpha_t *alpha)
{
    if (alpha->p == NULL) return 0;

    /* Skip non-alpha and check for end of string */
    while (*alpha->p && !isalpha(*alpha->p)) alpha->p++;
    if (*alpha->p == 0) return 0;

    /* Read token of alpha charactzers */
    alpha->str = alpha->p;
    while (isalpha(*alpha->p)) alpha->p++;
    alpha->len = alpha->p - alpha->str;

    return 1;
}

/*
 *      Example client code
 */
int main()
{
    char *str = "BOB123(&blah02938(*&91820FOO";
    struct alpha_t token = {str};

    while (next_alpha(&token)) {
        printf("'%.*s'\n", token.len, token.str);
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

This solution uses `isalpha`, as you already suggested. It is easily extended to other functions - you could even pass a delimiter on non-delimiter function as argument or make it part of the struct, for a customisable tokeniser.