# strtok, making the delimiter a range of ASCII values

Tags: c, ascii, delimiter, strtok

```
char *p_word;

p_word = strtok (p_input, " ,.-:\n1234567890");

while (p_word != NULL)
{
    printf ("%s\n", p_word);
    p_word = strtok (NULL, " ,.-:\n1234567890");
}
```

I'm reading in a text file and want to perform various functions on each word at a time, ignoring any characters that arent part of the alphabet.

I am wanting to know if there is a way instead of typing every single undesired character into the delimiter (e.g. " ,.-:\n1234567890"), that I can specify a range of ASCII decimal values I dont want, i.e. 0-64, or otherwise NOT alphabet characters.

Thanks

EDIT: I'm not allowed to use material that hasn't been taught so I dont think I can use functions from "ctype.h"

Comment: You could use the character class functions/macros such as `isalpha` from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243115/how-do-i-use-strtok-with-every-single-nonalpha-character-as-a-delimeter-c/26243667?s=1|0.1850#26243667

Comment: There are other questions that ask this.  A short answer is functions [`strspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html),
[`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html) and
[`strpbrk()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strpbrk.html) from standard C.

Comment: @pjxnanalana  You can write you own strtok function that will accept a predicate that determinates what characters are valid.

Comment: If you can't use what hasn't been taught, then (a) we can't help because we don't know what you have been taught, and (b) you should be able to answer using what you have been taught.  Note that limiting yourself like that is not a good long-term strategy; you need to be able to learn extra material because you'll never be formally taught all you need to know in order to program successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* use `strtok`, you can build a delimiter string like this (assumes ASCII character set) which excludes the alphabet.

```
char *p_word;
char delims[128];
int dindex;
int i;

dindex = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 'A'; i++)
    delims[dindex++] = i;
for (i = 'Z' + 1; i < 'a'; i++)
    delims[dindex++] = i;
for (i = 'z' + 1; i < 128; i++)
    delims[dindex++] = i;
delims[dindex] = '\0';

p_word = strtok (p_input, delims);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `strtok` function that will accept a predicate as the second parameter.

Of course you should use some other name for the function as you like.

Here is a demonstrative program. I have written a simplified predicate that checks any alpha ASCII character. You may use your own predicate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * strtok( char *s, int cmp( char ) )
{
    static char *p;

    if ( s ) p = s;

    if ( p )
    {
        while ( *p && cmp( *p ) ) ++p;
    }

    if ( !p || !*p ) return NULL;

    char *t = p++;

    while ( *p && !cmp( *p ) ) ++p;

    if ( *p ) *p++ = '\0';

    return t;
}

int cmp( char c )
{
    c |= 0x20;

    return c < 'a' || c > 'z'; 
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "   ABC123abc<>XYZ!@#xyz";
    char *p = strtok( s, cmp );

    while ( p )
    {
        puts( p );
        p = strtok( NULL, cmp );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
ABC
abc
XYZ
xyz
```

Using the predicate you can specify in it any rules for skipped characters.